# Is there a limit to the amount of energy that could be spent on bitcoin mining?

Tags: bitcoin

Since the difficulty of mining a bitcoin is adjusted upwards when the global mining capacity increases, is there any limit to how high the difficulty can get, and therefore a limit to how high the total amount of energy consumed by all miners could get?

Comment: No there is no such limit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. You should try to ask on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Because all miners are guessing a secret number. So there is no limitation of the number of miners are guessing the same wrong answers, hence, no upper limit to the amount of energy that could be spent on bitcoin mining.